# load innerhtml of different page in div of another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template `Details.aspx` page which has set of dropdown which gets filled in `ajax` call. i want all these **filled dropdown in another page's div**

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Details.aspx",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "text/html",
    success: function (data) {
        $data = $.parseHTML(data);
        console.log($data);
        $("#divDetails").html($("div #tblRegistration", $data).html());
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    });
```

**Error** : `parseerror` (in console)

When i run `Page2.aspx` in Net tab of my firebug i came to see only empty dropdown. Why it is not getting filled ? How can i get filled dropdown in Page2.aspx

P.S. : If i run `Default.aspx` isolated in browser dropdown gets filles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check that your ajax response has valid HTML code, and isn't broken, etc. As broken html can cause undesired results.

Next, use [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to convert the string to an html object.

```
$data = $.parseHTML(data);
$("#divDetails").html( $("div #tblRegistration",$data).html() );
```

Comment: On `GET` request do scripts of `Details.aspx` gets run ? means do they call ajax calls internally ?

Comment: @Shaggy No, no need. Only when the the browser has javascript enabled will Ajax work.